# Mouse click angle

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I'm creating a brick breaker game, and I need some help finding an angle.

Pretty much the game consists of blocks that, when hit, will cause you to lose 1 health. The point of the game is to hit the blocks with the balls to break them before they reach the bottom. If the ball hits a wall or a block, its trajectory is reversed.

I want the user to be able to click someone within the html canvas. Then the balls, which start in the center of the screen at the bottom of the canvas, will follow that angle. In other words, the user will click and the balls will move to that spot and then continue until it hits something.

I have some code here, But it probably won't help on how to achieve the angle thing.

```
   function animate(callback) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
  });
}

// canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// variables
var ballList = [];
var maxBalls = 1;
var checkAmount = 0;
var interval;
// onload/refresh/update/render
window.onload = function() {
  refresh();
}

function refresh() {
  update();
  render();
  animate(refresh);
}

function update() {
  document.addEventListener("click", spawn);
  for(var i = 0; i < ballList.length; i++) {
    ballList[i].move();
  }
}

function render() {
  context.fillStyle = '#000';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for(var i = 0; i < ballList.length; i++) {
    ballList[i].show();
  }
}

// ball
function Ball() {
  this.x = canvas.width / 2;
  this.y = canvas.height - 50;
  this.width = 10;
  this.height = 10;
  this.xVel = 5;
  this.yVel = -10;

  this.show = function() {
    context.fillStyle = '#fff';
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }

  this.move = function() {
    this.x += this.xVel;

    this.y += this.yVel;
    if(this.x >= canvas.width || this.x <= 0) {
      this.xVel *= -1;
    }
    if(this.y >= canvas.height || this.y <= 0) {
      this.yVel *= -1;
    }
  }
}

function spawn(event) {
  var xVel = (event.clientX - canvas.width / 2) / 90;
  if(ballList.length < maxBalls) {
    if(checkAmount < maxBalls) {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        ballList.push(new Ball((event.clientX)));
        checkAmount++;
        if(checkAmount > maxBalls) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          checkAmount = 0;
        }
      }, 10);
    }

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unit Vectors

To move an object from one point towards another you use a vector. A vector is just two numbers that represent a direction and a speed. It can be polar in that one number is an angle and the other is a distance, or cartesian that represent the vector as the amount of change in x and y.

### Cartesian unit vector

For this you can use either but I prefer the cartesian vector and a particular type called a unit vector. The unit vector is 1 unit long. In computer graphics the unit is normally the pixel.

So we have a point to start at

```
var startX = ?
var startY = ?
```

And a point the we want to head towards

```
var targetX = ?
var targetY = ?
```

We want the unit vector from start to target,

```
var vectorX = targetX - startX;
var vectorY = targetY - startY;
```

The vector's length is the distance between the two points. This is not so handy so we will turn it into a unit vector by dividing both the x and y by the length

```
var length = Math.sqrt(vectorX * vectorX + vectorY * vectorY);
var unitVectX = vectorX / length;
var unitVectY = vectorY / length;
```

Now we have a one pixel long unit vector.

The Ball will start at start

```
var ballX = startX
var ballY = startY
```

And will move at a speed of 200 pixels per second (assuming 60fps)

```
var ballSpeed = 200 / 60;
```

Now to move the ball just add the unit vector times the speed and you are done. Well till the next frame that is.

```
 ballX += unitVectX * ballSpeed;
 ballY += unitVectY * ballSpeed;
```

Using the cartesian makes it very easy to bounce off of walls that are aligned to the x or y axis.

```
if(ballX + ballRadius > canvas.width){
      ballX = canvas.width - ballRadius;
      unitVectX = - unitVectX;
}
```

#### Polar vector

You can also use polar coordinates. As we use a unit vector the polar unit vector just needs the direction. You use the trig function atan2

```
 // get the direction in radians
 var polarDirection = Math.atan2(targetY - startY, targetX - startX);
```

The direction is in radians, many poeple don't like radians and convert to degrees, but there is no need to know which way it is going just as long as it goes in the correct direction. To remember radians is easy. 360 degrees is 2 radian 180 is 1 randian 90 is 0.5. The actual units used are PI (not many people know many of the digits of pi but you don't need to). So 270 degree is 1.5 radians or as a number 1.5 * Math.PI.

The angles start at the 3 o'clock point (pointing to the right of screen) as 0 radians or 0 deg then clockwise 90deg is at 6 o'clock 0.5 radian, and 180deg 1 radian at 6 o'clock and so on.

To move the ball with the polarDirection you need to use some more trig.

```
 // do this once a frame
 ballX += Math.cos(polarDirection) * ballSpeed;
 ballY += Math.sin(polarDirection) * ballSpeed;
 // note that the cos and sin actually generate the cartesian unit vector
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * @param {number} x1 - x coordinate of the first point
 * @param {number} y1 - y coordinate of the first point
 * @param {number} x2 - x coordinate of the second point
 * @param {number} y2 - y coordinate of the second point
 * @return {number} - the angle (between 0 and 360)
 */
function getDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    // might be negative:
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    // correct, positive angle:
    return (angle + 360) % 360;
}
```

I wrote this function for a similar purpose. Don't forget that you might have to negate x.

Comment: `atan2(dy,dx)` returns 0 when `dy = 0` and `dx = 1` and is pointing to the right of the screen and the y axis for the canvas moves down not up.